# ,Vb.net RDLC Filter by Word

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, reportviewer

how to filter Data set ,I want only to retrieve is "REPAIRED " , and filter by between date.

using report viewer

and this is my query for Dataset job_order query

```
SELECT        ID, cust_jo, cust_name, cust_num, cust_brand, cust_model, cust_imeiserial, cust_problem, cust_entrust, cust_repaircost, cust_downpayment, cust_balance,                        tech_remarks, cust_reciveperson, jo_statusdate_added, date_modified, releasedby, releasedate FROM job_order WHERE (jo_status LIKE 'REPAIRED') 




  Public Property strReport As String
Private Sub ReportView_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DBDataSet.job_order' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.job_orderTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DBDataSet.job_order)
    Dim rptDataSource As ReportDataSource

    Try
        With Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport
            .ReportPath = "D:\VBProjects\Sales Inventory\Sales Inventory\Report\Report1.rdlc"
            .DataSources.Clear()
        End With
        Dim ds As New Sales_Inventory.DBDataSet
        Dim da As New Sales_Inventory.DBDataSetTableAdapters.job_orderTableAdapter

        da.Fill(ds.job_order)


        rptDataSource = New ReportDataSource("DataReport", ds.Tables("job_order"))
        Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptDataSource)

        Me.ReportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, My.Application.Info.Title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try


    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
```

[REPORT SAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjwaK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter using query in your dataset

go to you Dataset Right Click Add Query

Add this Query

```
SELECT * FROM job_order WHERE COLUMN LIKE 'YOUR WORD'
```